# Possible to do this in better than O(n^2) time?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, data-structures

The problem I'm trying to solve gives me a matrix like

```
10101
11100
11010
00101
```

where the rows are supposed to represented topics that a person knows; e.g. Person 1, represented by `10101`, knows topics 1, 3 and 5, but not 2 or 4. I need to find the maximum number of topics that a 2-person team could know; e.g. the team that is Person 1 and 3 knows all the topics because between `10101` and `11010` there are  `1`s at every index.

I have an O(n^2) solution

```
    string[] topic = new string[n];
    for(int topic_i = 0; topic_i < n; topic_i++)
    {
       topic[topic_i] = Console.ReadLine();   
    }
    IEnumerable<int> teamTopics = 
        from t1 in topic
        from t2 in topic
        where !Object.ReferenceEquals(t1, t2)
        select t1.Zip(t2, (c1, c2) => c1 == '1' || c2 == '1').Sum(b => b ? 1 : 0);
    int max = teamTopics.Max();
    Console.WriteLine(max);
```

which is passing all the test cases it doesn't time out on. I suspect the reason it's not fast enough has to do with the time complexity rather than the overhead of the LINQ machinery. But I can't think of a better way to do it.

I thought that maybe I could map the indices of topics to the persons who know them, like

```
1 -> {1,2,3}
2 -> {2,3}
3 -> {1,2,4}
4 -> {3}
5 -> {1,4}
```

but I can't think of where to go from there.

Can you supply me with a "hint"?

Comment: An already working solution should go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Allways remember: [premature optimization is the root of all evil] (http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) . Do you really care on performance of that code? Or are your real issues somewhere else and you refactor all your code for nothing?

Comment: ...isn't this simply counting the number of 1-bits in the inclusive OR of all topic bitstrings? There are [well-known tricks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html) for speeding up things like that (assuming your number of topics is strictly limited).

Comment: @JeroenMostert indeed, hamming weight (counting bits) of `skills[i] | skills[j]` for all triangular combinations of `i`/`j` - but that is still O(n^2)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem

Comment: @MarcGravell: right, *a* two person team, as in, any two persons thrown together, not a fixed list of two person teams. That wasn't immediately clear from the description.

Comment: The fastest solution would be to create a sparse matrix that only contained the cells with ones.  Right now you have to check every row of the matrix, with my solution you only have to check the cells with 1's.

Comment: @jdweng that doesn't help if every row contains a `1`. If the matrix was random then there would only be a 1 / 2^n chance of there being a row of all `0`s.

Comment: Sparse matrix have advantages when the number of non-zero cells are small compared to the total number of cells.  You cannot assume that it is random.  A random approximation of a sparse cell can only be used if you based it on the average number of non zero cells in a column.

Comment: @jdweng yes, *if* we knew that most people had only a small percentage of the skills, a sparse matrix could be helpful.  But we don't know that that's the case, and the one example we were given shows a non-sparsely populated matrix, so it doesn't seem likely.

Comment: This posting is a discussion of algorithms with a very small sample of actual data.  I simply gave to answer to a method for reducing an O(n^2) algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have n people and m topics.

I would argue that your algorithm is O(n^2 * m), where n is number of people, because:

1. `from t1 in topic` gets you O(n)
2. `from t2 in topic` gets you to O(n^2)
3. `t1.Zip(t2 ...` get you to O(n^2 * m)

An optimisation that I see is first to modify strings a bit:

- s1 = '0101', where i-th element shows whether a person i knows 1st topic
- s2 = '1111', where i-th element shows whether a person i knows 2nd topic.

etc...

Then you analyse string s1. You pick all possible pairs of 1s (`O(n^2)` elements) that show pairs of people that together know 1st topic. Then go pick a pair from that list and check whether they know 2nd topic as well and so on. When they don't, delete it from the list and move on to another pair.

Unfortunately this looks to be `O(n^2 * m)` as well, but this should be quicker in practise. For very sparse matrix, it should be close to O(n<sup>2</sup>), and for dense matrices it should find a pair pretty soon.

Comment: It's not O(n^3) because the number of rows is different (and likely independent from) the number of columns.  If `n` is the number of rows (people) and `m` is the number of columns (topics), the complexity would be better expressed as O(m n^2).  That reduces to O(n^2) if the number of columns is constant.

Comment: In the OP's case `n` is the number of rows, not the number of columns, so comparing the columns of each row is not an O(n) operation.  If you considered the number of columns to be `k` then the OP's code would be O(k*n^2), but it would appear as if `k` is always small, and won't be able to scale up to infinity, and so isn't being considered.

Comment: `t1.Zip(t2...)` does not make it O(n^3), it makes it O(n^2*t), where n is the number of people, and t is the number of topics.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the answer

Comment: But the OP does not bound the number of topics, and we don't know the relationship between the number of topics and people, I think O(n^2 * m) is more accurate than O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

Thoughts:

- as a speculative optimization: you could do an O(n) sweep to find the individual with the highest number of skills (largest hamming weight); note them, and stop if they have everything: pair them with anyone, it doesn't matter
- you can exclude anyone without testing who **only** has skilled shared with the "best" individual - we already know about everything they can offer and have tested against everyone; so only test if `(newSkills & ~bestSkills) != 0` - meaning: the person being tested has something that the "best" worker didn't have; this leaves m workers with complementary skills plus the "best" worker (you must include them explicitly, as the `~`/`!=0` test above will fail for them)
- now do another O(m) sweep of possible partners - checking to see if the "most skilled" plus any other gives you all the skills (obviously stop earlier if a single member has all the skills); but either way: keep track of best combination for later reference
- you can further *half* the time by only considering the triangle, not the square - meaning: you compare row `0` to rows `1`-`(m-1)`, but row `1` to rows `2`-`(m-1)`, row `5` to `6`-`(m-1)`, etc
- you can significantly improve things by using integer bit math along with an efficient "hamming weight" algorithm (to count the set bits) rather than strings and summing
- get rid of the LINQ
- short-circuit if you get all ones (compare to `~((~0)<<k)`, where `k` is the number of bits being tested for)
- remember to compare any result to the "best" combination we found against the most skilled worker

This is still `O(n) + O(m^2)` where m <= n is the number of people with skills **different to** the most skilled worker

---

Pathological but technically correct answer:

insert a `Thread.Sleep(FourYears)` - all solutions are now essentially O(1)

Comment: Inserting a sleep for 4 years does not make the solution O(1).  Adding a large constant to any value is irrelevant to the big O value, as it will still *eventually* scale up to the point where even that constant value is a miniscule portion of the program, it will just take longer to get to that point.  The pathological answer would be to say that there's a finite number of `int` values in C#, so you could pre-compute the answer for every possible set of integers in C#, resolving the entire algorithm to a cache lookup (which would be O(1) in time), despite taking *lots* of memory.

Comment: @Servy sure, for an *incredibly* large `n`, but for most realistic problems (that would have ever completed), it is moot and the O(1) dominates

Comment: I forgot to mention something important. The second part of the problem is `On the second line, print the number of 2-person teams that can know the maximum number of topics.`, so even if on the first sweep I find a pair with all the topics I still have to find all pairs that have all the topics.

Comment: The whole point of Big O is that you're taking the limit as all input values go to infinity.  If you're speaking strictly of finite input values then *you're not talking about Big O*.

Comment: @user7127000 everything I said understood that (pair thing); it takes that into account. The only thing it does different there is check whether any combination of "most skilled"+any other has *all* skills, in which case you can stop immediately

Comment: @Servy in purely academic terms: sure; but in the real world, knowing what order-of-magnitude your N is : is very important in any meaningful code. I only care about useful code. Pointless academic purism has remarkably little use.

Comment: If you think Big O isn't a useful metric for you, then by all means, don't use it, and use other metrics.  There are lots of tools for describing relevant performance characteristics of programs in finite, rather than infinite, spaces.  Of course, by your new criteria, a program that sleeps for 4 years is, in a practical sense, not a constant time program, but rather an *infinite* time program, as 4 years is an unacceptably long time scale for most any application.

Comment: @Servy big O is *very* useful; but it needs to be taken **in conjunction with** other data especially what the scale of n is. In isolation it is much less useful than computer scientists would have you believe. Heck, with modern computers another key question is "can I parallelize it? how about for a GPU? Or are there forced linear pieces?"

Comment: @MarcGravell Sure, absolutely.  But the point there is that you keep track of what the Big O is, but clarify that with whether or not that will actually be acceptable, in context, for the realistic values given.  For example, some algorithm may be O(n^4) but you're okay with it because n will always be small, or something else might be O(n) and it be unacceptably high because there won't be time for that with such a large data set.  The point remains that adding a constant, even a large constant, doesn't change the big O value, even if it changes the practical usefulness of the code

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is asymptotically as efficient as it gets, because you need to examine all pairs to arrive at the maximum. You can make your code more efficient by replacing strings with [`BitArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx) objects, like this:

```
var topic = new List<BitArray>();
string line;
while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null) {
    topic.Add(new BitArray(line.Select(c => c=='1').ToArray()));
}
var res =
   (from t1 in topic
    from t2 in topic
    select t1.Or(t2).Count).Max();
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/jiI8k9)